# How do I get the text from a div using Webdriver-IO

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, webdriver-io

How can I get a value from following, using Webdriver-IO for creating automation script:

```html
    <div class="metric-value ng-binding" 
         ng-style="{'font-size': vis.params.fontSize+'pt'}" style="font-size: 60pt;">
      84
    </div>
```

I tried

```js
element(by.binding('**')).getText().then(function (value) {
  console.log(value);
})
```

But it is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest (synchronous) version of WebdriverIO it would look something like this:

```
var text = browser.getText('div.metric-value.ng-binding');
console.log(text);
```

Otherwise, running the async version:

```
client.getText('div.metric-value.ng-binding', function(err, message){
    console.log(message)
})
```